# Get all series from a chart with Google Apps Script

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with 30 charts and I'm trying to iterate over all of them updating the colors of the background and the series.

Even though I could do it blindly, I'd rather be able to look at all the series in a chart first so that I could add extra logic based on the number of series, if it is already using one of my custom colors, title, etc. The problem is that I couldn't find a way to get the series from a chart.

Given that I can modify the series with `setOptions` I thought something like `sheet.getCharts()[0].getOptions().get('series')` would work, but it returns `Access to class "(class)" is prohibited.` when I try to log it.

Any advice on how to get an object where I can read information about the series in a chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its like hashmap (key/value) when you set option put key and value and when you get it try to use json to get the oject value too

```
  function myfunction() {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var len = sheet.getCharts().length;
      for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
      var bg=sheet.getCharts()[i].getOptions().get('backgroundColor.fill');
      var s=sheet.getCharts()[i].getOptions().get('series.0.color');
       }
    }
```

Comment: I don't have any problem updating the series. My problem is to read them. I want to use different colors based on the number of series in a chart (e.g. if I have only 1 line, 2 lines or multiple lines) and it would be even better if I could read the title of each one to decide which color to use.

Comment: In particular if I could read the settings before trying to change just the color I'd be able to replicate the settings already applied and avoid my charts breaking, such as secondary axis, headers, etc.

Comment: Yup, that helps! Not what I was hoping for, but it is what it is if they can't design a better API... In particular because I'll need to read every option individually in order to be able to change *just* the color since everything else resets. :(

Comment: @Chemiadel   thanks for this. It seems to work for some properties, not all. for example, get('title') works, but get('title.Position') or get('title.position') or get('titlePosition') doesn't. It doesn't give an error, but the returned value is null.

Comment: i think it is not available in G Sheets, because when you go to edit chart > Customize > Charts & axis titles > Select Chart Title . you won't find something called Title position there's just Alignment option in format